# Androidstudio not starting qemu

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

Until yesterday AndroidStudio would always start the qemu emulator, I then upgraded to 2.3.3. and now Studio starts only the emulator64-x86 instead of qemu and the emulator opens up and a pop up on the device says "com.google.process.gapps" process was interrupted.

The log file shows the crash was caused by:

```
      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade 
      database from version 11 to 2
```

The app is not using any DB.

Would appreciate any ideas of (1) why qemu is not starting and (2) why the crash and how I could fix it.

Comment: have you tried update emulator?

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows machine:**

Take a look into the folder `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator` and into `C:\Users\YourUserName\.android\avd` (I mean your Windows user name instead of `YourUserName`). In second path find the name of folder with virtual disk you want to run on emulator - for example **Nexus_5_API_23.avd**

Create text file with following content (you will need a virtual disk folder name **without .avd**!):

```
@echo on
cd C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator
emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -gpu host
```

Rename it to the `emulator_23.cmd` and start it with double click - qemu should start up.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am on a Mac.

Comment: I have no idea what happens on Mac, but I suppose you can find the same folders and write a similar command file too.